# JavaScript: How can I countdown an Array 10 Seconds?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a countdown that counts from 10 to 1 secondly. The current second/index should be printed in a div-tag. But it doesn't show the number but it goes into the function. AND it doesn't end, so it goes into a never-ending.

`

var myCountdown = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

```
  setInterval(timer(), 1000);
  timer = () => {

      for(i = 0; i < myCountdown.length; i++){

        console.log(myCountdown[i]);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += myCountdown[i];

    }}
```

`

Comment: An interval is terminated only if you terminate it explicitly (see [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)).

Comment: Actually the function `timer` will be invoked only once. The line `setInterval(timer(), 1000);` should read `setInterval(timer, 1000);` otherwise you're invoking `timer()` and pass the result to `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Teemu mentioned in the comments you have to stop the interval.

```
var token = setInterval(timer, 1000); // Set the timer function to run every 1000ms until we tell it to stop.
var element = document.getElementById("test");
var i = 10;
function timer() {

    if (i <= 0) {
        clearInterval(token); // Stop counting down.
    } else {
        i -= 1; // Count down.
        element.innerHTML = i;
    }

}
```

crystalbit's answer also works, it just uses `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let i = 10;
const work = () => {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = i;
  if (i--) setTimeout(work, 1000);
}
work();
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go with an array, here is the solution:

```js
const countdown = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (countdown.length) document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = countdown.shift();
    else clearInterval(timer)
}, 1000)
```

Run this snippet for a demo:

```js
const countdown = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

let timer = setInterval(() => {
if (countdown.length) document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = countdown.shift();
    else clearInterval(timer)
}, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background:tomato;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='test'></h1>
```